# A manifold multiplied by scalar

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a compact $2$-dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$,$\lambda >0$,$\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ and $M':=\lambda M=\{\lambda x|x\in M\}$.

a)Prove that $M'$ is a $2$-dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

b)Prove that: $area(M')=\lambda^2area(M)$.

I don't know how to approach this question...any help?

Comment: What is your definition of manifold? It shouldn't be too hard to leverage the fact that this definition holds for $M$ into showing that it holds for $M'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any chart $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to M$, the function $\lambda g:\mathbb{R^2}\to \lambda M$ gives you a chart for $\lambda M$. The differentiability of compositions $g_1\circ g_2^{-1}$ gives us the differentiability of $(\lambda g_1)\circ (\lambda g_2)^{-1}=\lambda\circ g_1\circ g_2^{-1}\circ \lambda^{-1}$, where $\lambda$ is the multiplication by $\lambda$. We need to take into account that multiplication by $\lambda$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

For (b) just compute the volume form on $M$ and do the change of variable.
In a chart $g$ the form is $|g_x\times g_y|dxdy$. For $\lambda M$ it would be $|\lambda g_x\times \lambda g_y|dxdy=\lambda^2|g_x\times g_y|dxdy$

Comment: Your first $\Bbb R$ should be $\Bbb R^2$.